# MAAS Commissioning Failed timed out after 0:20:00

Tags: maas

I have installed MAAS and tried to set it up. I'm currently setting up virtual machines to use as nodes with MAAS, and have selected the power type as virsh. After manually adding the machine(node), within a few minutes of the commissioning process, it failed, stating `'Commissioning' timed out after 0:20:00`. Here's the MAAS [log](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23301741/).

I tried a few methods of troubleshooting but had no luck. Below are the troubleshooting steps which I have tried.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-region-controller
sudo dpkg-reconfigure maas-cluster-controller
```

Please advise me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the right network settings in MAAS. The VMs might not be getting the right gateway. The gateway should also provide internet connectivity.

You can try skipping the commissioning process by adding a machine manually. See "[Manually add nodes](https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/nodes.html)" section in the MAAS docs.

Also check out the [general Maas troubleshooting steps](https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/troubleshooting.html)

Comment: Still i am facing the same issue. Do you have any alternative solution for the same?

Comment: Which exact guide have you been following?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information about the problem, like network settings and full history of machine events for the corresponding node